# A easy algorithm that takes two INTs and returns a randomish INT

Tags: c++, c, random

The function would be something like this.

```
int generateSortOfRandomInt(int X, int Y){

/*
Your program

*/

return randomINT that is always the same for X and Y
}
```

It would be nice if
generateSortOfRandomInt(5,15) != generateSortOfRandomInt(15,5)

A example would be something like

```
int value1 = generateSortOfRandomInt(1, 3);  // 546547
int value2 = generateSortOfRandomInt(3, 1);  // 134566
int value3 = generateSortOfRandomInt(1, 3);  // 546547 THE SAME AS value1
int value4 = generateSortOfRandomInt(2, 3);  // 646621
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there not a rand() method in C++?

Comment: Use `<random>` or `rand()` with a non-commutative operation?

Comment: Or you could use a hash function.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question? What problem are you trying to solve? It seems like an arbitrary set of rules you've imposed (and presumably there is a good reason you don't want to use the randomizer functions that come with the standard library), so you'll need to give us more details about your unique situation.

Comment: To firther expand on what Cody said, please read this [meta post on the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Interesting comment: *The easiest way to get to the real problem is usually asking Why five times*.  why? turns out it's some sort of simulation...

Comment: What you're looking for has ***nothing*** to do with randomness. Allthough, you could use a random **salt** to hide the input correlation somwehat. That'd be obfuscation.

Comment: so pepper doesn't work?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
int generateSortOfRandomInt(int X, int Y)
{
    srand(x*x+y);

    return rand();
}
```

Comment: That'll work. I removed srand and rand and came up with              return(x*x+y * 1103515245 + 12345)%1000 because I only need values from 1-1000

Comment: @user315684: I'm not saying this to draw attention to my answer, rather just for your information.  But what you've done there is basically implement a hash function.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley your completely right of course. But this way I can avoid using std::hash and move the code into OpenCl which makes my simulation faster. Which I never mentioned so your solution is far prettier under most conditions.

Comment: -1 This is horrible (you'll interfere with other uses of rand() throughout your program and any libraries you call) and unnecessary (an xor of a hash of X and Y would serve just fine, using boost::hash, C++11's or any of thousands of other readily available implementations).

Comment: @user315684 Why is this the accepted answer? You don't even _use_ it as such?

Comment: @sehe because the code for rand() under my system is            inline int rand()
{
 return rseed = (rseed * 1103515245 + 12345) & RAND_MAX;
}

Comment: @user315684 That's precisely the reason why this answer is bogus and should not be accepted. Using `srand` only serves to cripple the rest of your application in case it uses `rand()` elsewhere. It may even become unthread-safe, or open large security holes by having predictable random sequences.

Answer (score 6):

Use a hash function, e.g.

```
return std::hash<int>()(std::hash<int>()(x) + y);
```

Comment: Doesn't hashing an int just return the same int (cast to unsigned)? So effectively, you're computing `x+y`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: That would be a pretty terrible hashing algorithm if it did, so no, not likely. Try if for yourself, and tell me your results.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/pgMgcy) are the results :)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley And [here](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=093c286c83010b5d8de076bf01ca0119).

Comment: @FredOverflow: In that case. Use a different hashing algorithm.  I did write `e.g.`.

Comment: If you want to hash 32 bits to 32 bits, then using anything other than the identity function would be pointless. In my mind, `std::hash<int>` does the right thing by simply returning its input.

Comment: @FredOverflow: But it wouldn't work for this purpose, right? Then choose a different one.  I don't use GCC, and my implementation's hash function isn't just the identity function. And I've seen arguments for why it shouldn't be, so I didn't think it would be implemented that way. I guess I was wrong. So choose a different hash function.

Comment: Right, because hash functions (as used for hash tables, not for security purposes) are not supposed to be *random*. They are supposed to distribute the input domain "uniformly" to the output domain, and as long as the input domain is a subset of the output domain, the identity function is perfect.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I see your point. I guess I've never considered the distinction between hashes used for cryptography and those used for hash tables, and made the age old mistake of assuming that if it's done one way on one implementation, it's done that way (or similar) on all of them.

Comment: "If you want to hash 32 bits to 32 bits, then using anything other than the identity function would be pointless" - not so - a general purpose hash function would ideally map each input to a distinct output in a seemingly random but repeatable way.  For hash tables, the key factor is that even if you're hashing a 32-bit input, it's not necessarily the case that all values are equally likely as inputs, but you do want the outputs scattered nicely across your buckets regardless.

Comment: @TonyD How is a non-identity hash function going to scatter the values better than the identity function? Can you give an example?

Comment: @FredOverflow: there are many ways to do it - the absolute simplest to understand is to use the value being hashed as an index in a table of random numbers... if it's say a 32-bit value, you could have 4 tables with 256 values each.  Also common to use maths functions that happen to scatter well - math proofs are over my head, but there are examples on the Wikipedia entry for hash functions.

Answer (score 6):

```
int generateSortOfRandomInt(int X, int Y)
{
    return (X * 0xcafebabe) ^ (Y * 0xdeadbeef);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Search  Perlin noise for 2D . if I Remember Correctly this will give same output for the same input.

Comment: :( then it would be less random. But that is a solution.

Comment: I thought u have to get same output for the same input values as you said in the example

Comment: Perlin noise generates pseudo-random number(not exactly a random number). But you have a lot of control over how the output should be while using perlin. http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm

Comment: The main issue is that it interpolates between values which I don't care about but I could have just taken the Random generate and removed the sign stuff.  So this equation from the link would have worked.  return ( 1.0 - ( (x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague. There are a million different ways do to this.

Some ideas are:
Divide the numbers together and move the decimal point to create a number.

However based on how you're getting different results based on the order of the numbers given as parameters. I would use the numbers to shift the bits left or right based on the parameters
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Comment: Add links like this `[link text](http://........com)`